# Assitance with regex

Tags: regex, match

I'm having a problem with getting only the nth match of a pattern.
Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have the following text and I'm trying to only get the third match:

```
/* 
   Line 1: this is line one
   Line 2: this could also be line one
   Line 3: this is the line I'm interested in because is the one 
   Line 4: just some random line
   Line 5: this is not the line I want, it's not the one
*/
```

I am using the following regex to fine lines that have a start string of "this" and end string of "one". So my regex is:

```
(?:^this.*?one)
```

Using RegEx Tester v3.2.0.0, I'm able to get the lines that match. The lines are 1, 2, 3 and 5. Line 4 is ignore because it obviously doesn't match.

Now I'm only interested in getting line 3 in return and ignore the other matches. So I thought that by using the occurrence {nth} and appending that to the end of my regex I would get the 3rd match. It doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure how to do this and I'm hoping someone can provide assistance. Any help is appreciated it. Thank you!

**UPDATE 1**

I'm sorry if my questions is confusing. I am only interested in creating a pattern that would only return a match for the 3rd line.

I started working on a pattern that would find all of the lines that matched a starting and ending string, so I came up with (?:^this.*?one).

I started reading online trying to find out if I can also specify in regex to only give me the 3rd match of the pattern. I started reading about occurrences and I thought I could use that to specify the nth occurrence of the pattern. Maybe I'm not understanding exactly how to use occurrence. That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Why the 3rd line? What can help us identify that line from the others?

Comment: This question is not very clear. Are you just asking how to get the nth string that matches a given regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew He always wants to select 3rd line *(methinks)* .. That can be a clue ..

Comment: Like [`(?:^this.*one\r?\n){2}^(this.*one$)`](https://regex101.com/r/hI0uJ4/2)? Or shorter: [`(?:(^this.*one)\r?\n){3}`](https://regex101.com/r/hI0uJ4/3)? The value will be in Group 1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew May you please let me to use your shorter version in my answer?

Comment: I can let you use all, but **explain why this is working**. I hate "try-this" answers and won't like when you take my suggestions in such an answer.

Comment: I think that his example just happens to have 3 matching lines in a row, but it would be possible to have a non-matching line in there and so it could be the 4th, 5th, etc.

Comment: Put in which language you are using as a tag. `Java` | `C#` | `Perl` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If always you need to get third line, try this:

```
/(?:^this.*one\r?\n){2}^(this.*one$)/gm
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hI0uJ4/2)

- `(?:` is a non capturing group, in other word you **cannot** use it like `$1`
- `^` matches the begining of line
- `.*one` matches everything til `one` word and then `\r?\n` means new line
- `{2}` it limits matching to select just two fist lines
- `^` the beginning of third line
- `(` capturing group, in other word you can grab the value of this capturing group by `$1`
- `this.*one` matches this pattern: `this{anything}one`
- `$` matches end of line

---

BTW, as @wiktor-stribiżew mentioned in the comments, this could be a shorter version:

```
/(?:(^this.*one)\r?\n){3}/gm
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hI0uJ4/3)

---

Also if you need to grab comment part (what is after `//`), then try this: *(however I hardly think you need this)*

```
/(?:^this.*one\r?\n){2}^(this.*one(:?\s*\/\/\s*.*$))/gm
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nB3tF7/2)

Comment: Why should people "try" something if *you* do not know why it should work? **Points are nothing, knowledge is everything**.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Do you mean I have to explain my regex?

Comment: I do not want my suggestions being reprinted without any explanations.

Comment: Ok, but it will still fail in one case, and this whole approach may fail (see [jacob.m's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491969/assitance-with-regex#comment58677381_35491969)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Heh .. That's ridiculous ...! I cannot spend a few time again to understand a poor question .. I'm out

Comment: @Shafizadeh even though you criticized about the question being poorly written, you and WiktorStribiżew actually provided the correct answer to my question. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Well, glad to help `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you could just change it to a capturing group and add the global and multiline options and then grab the third group ($3 or whatever your specific case uses).

This one gives you all matches, and if you want the nth then grab the nth group.

```
/(^this.*?one)/mg
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/tP2tU0/1)